# ¿Completar tarea GxFlow fuera del Inbox con un objeto GeneXus?

Tags: genexus, genexus15, genexusxev3

Muy buenas, estoy realizando un desarrollo con un proceso en GxFlow, y en cierta tarea quiero que se permita completar fuera del Inbox con un Objeto GeneXus

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que leas un poco más la documentación de GXFlow. Ahí te explican bastante bien como hacer este tipo de cosas.
En particular esta este artículo: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?9990,HowTo%3A+Closing+and+Completing+a+Workitem+Using+Workflow+Datatypes que hace referencia a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Sí, pero en mi caso yo quisiera completar la tarea fuera del Inbox de GxFlow, en otras pantalla GeneXus, pero no dentro de GxFlow

Comment: Justamente Fernando...para eso es la Workflow API. Hay que investigar y probar. No es nada complicado lo que estás intentando hacer.